# How to query data from AspenONE IP21 Historian using Power BI?

Tags: database, server, powerbi, datasource, aspen

I wish to do a PowerBI dashboard using data from IP21 historian.
There is currently no automated export from IP21 and there are lots of tables to update manually.
Thus I am wondering, is it possible to directly use IP21 as the data source in PowerBI ?

Many thanks

Comment: Hello,
I don't know much about PowerBI (thick client? azure server?), but querying IP21 server is possible using web api or windows ODBC SqlPlus server.

Comment: Hello @Madgui  I don't know either I'm really just discovering everything haha. Thank you for your answer ! I'll look into that